# API endpoint returning other headers when accessing by php and python

Tags: python, php, curl, cookies, roblox

I am trying to make code, which comunicates with API. It updates users roblox group rank. Firstly, I wrote the code in Python. It had no problem. But then I tried to "translate" it to PHP and for some reason it doesnt return the same headers as in Python

I want to make group ranking system. For authorisation purposes, I have to set `.ROBLOSECURITY` cookie. But even after that I have to send one authorisation request to `auth.roblox.com`. After sending request to that endpoint with `.ROBLOSECURITY` cookie set, it will return with header `X-CSRF-TOKEN`. Both of these values have to be set for valid authorisation.

```
import requests
cookie = "_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|..."
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies[".ROBLOSECURITY"] = cookie
req = session.post(
    url="https://auth.roblox.com/"
)
if "X-CSRF-Token" in req.headers:
    session.headers["X-CSRF-Token"] = req.headers["X-CSRF-Token"]
```

This Python code does that and it works
These are headers returned when adding `print(req.headers)`.

`{'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'date': 'Tue, 12 Dec 2023 16:03:33 GMT', 'server': 'Kestrel', 'access-control-expose-headers': 'X-CSRF-TOKEN', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'x-csrf-token': 'the value', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=3600', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'roblox-machine-id': '2444778a591b', 'x-roblox-region': 'us-central', 'x-roblox-edge': 'fra4', 'report-to': '{"group":"network-errors","max_age":604800,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://ncs.roblox.com/upload"}]}', 'nel': '{"report_to":"network-errors","max_age":604800,"success_fraction":0.001,"failure_fraction":1}'}`
When I have similar php script:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$authapi = "https://auth.roblox.com/";
$authcookie = "_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|...";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $authapi);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$cookie = ".ROBLOSECURITY=$authcookie";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",  'Cookie: ' . $cookie
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
echo $response;
```

The echo returns this.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 16
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 12 Dec 2023 16:13:33 GMT
server: Kestrel
cache-control: no-cache
strict-transport-security: max-age=3600
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
roblox-machine-id: 83cc37212edc
x-roblox-region: us-central
x-roblox-edge: fra4
report-to: {"group":"network-errors","max_age":604800,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://ncs.roblox.com/upload"}]}
nel: {"report_to":"network-errors","max_age":604800,"success_fraction":0.001,"failure_fraction":1}

{"message":"OK"}
```

There is no `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header in there. What can be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: My first guess would be because you are specifying CURLOPT_NOBODY, it is switching the request type to HEAD.  If you remove that line, does that change things?  Isn't the request supposed to be a POST?

Comment: @RobEyre I deleted that line and it changes nothing. When I add (CURLOPT_POST, 1), it returns 400

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps you could also remove the part that is manually specifying CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER and just use CURLOPT_COOKIE instead.  You could also add CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT to track what is actually being sent (perhaps there is also an equivalent in Python, for comparison?)

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your code a little, and tried this:

```php
$authapi = "https://auth.roblox.com/";
$authcookie = "_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|...";
    
$curl = curl_init($authapi);
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => ".ROBLOSECURITY=$authcookie",
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
echo $response;
```

It returned a x-csrf-token in the response

Comment: Alright, it works, I just had to change the method to post. Anyway, when I upload the script to my hosting, after putting `CURLOPT_POST => true`, it returns 400 bad request. I had to try this script on localhost (its working there, the post doesnt return 400, but the token)

Comment: Alright, it is working now, all I had to do was change `CURLOPT_POST => true` to `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST'`, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

```
$authapi = "https://auth.roblox.com/";
$authcookie = "_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|..."; 
$curl = curl_init($authapi);
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => ".ROBLOSECURITY=$authcookie",
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
]);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
echo $response;
```